# jQuery/JavaScript regex to match any three first characters followed by an exact string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need a regular expression to validate a form, based on the value of a drop down. The value, however, is randomly generated by PHP (but is always a 2 digit number).

It needs to be valid for "38|One Evening" The number 38 is what's going to change. So far, I have

```
//return value of dropdown
var priceOption = $("#price_option-4").val();

//make sure it ends with "One Evening"
var oneEvening = priceOption.match(/^ * + 'One Evening' $/);
```

Which I thought would match any string as long as it's followed by "one evening"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

strings are not to be use with regex, you should just write what you want to match\test inside the regex literal, without the quotes.

```
   /^\d{2}\|One Evening$/.test(priceOption);
//  ^^^^^^                          Begins with two digits
//        ^^                        Escaped the | meta char.
//          ^^^^^^^^^^^^            Then until the end: One Evening
```

Comment: Wait, sorry (I should've thought of this first): `.test()` is a method of the regex object, not strings?

Comment: @Blazemonger. It means I need to take a rest, I got a fever... I fixed it and went to sleep. :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply use

```
/^\d\d\|One Evening$/.test(priceOption);
```

Comment: priceOption is a string and strings do not have a "test" method.

Answer (score 1):

For xx|One Evening

```
/^\d{2}\|One Evening$/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/^.+?One Evening$/
```

Breaking it down

```
// ^ starts with
// . any character
// + quantifier - one or more of preceding character
// ? non-greedy - ensure regex stops at One Evening.
// One Evening = literal text
// $ match end of string.
```

Note that my answer reflects the requirement to match any sequence of characters, then `One Evening`.

I think you may be better off being more specific and ensuring you definitely have two numeric characters.

Comment: Why the `.+?` ? What's wrong with all the other answers? And you forgot the `|` after the digits.

Comment: I pretty much broke this down exactly.  Didn't forget the | either.  Just unnecessary if you are using the . character.

Answer (score -1):

If you can it is best to be specific. Try the following:

```
// <start of string> <2 digits> <|One Evening> <end of string>
/^\d{2}\|One Evening$/.test( priceOption );
```